# Google Play Subscription- Is there any way to give discount on in app subscription?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am planning to create a yearly subscription package. Those who subscribe in promotional period i.e November 2021 they will get access to premium content with the price of £48 for the whole year. But if they subscribe after the the promotional period they will be charged £96 for the whole year. Is it possible to configure this in google play subscription ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can it is called [Introductory price](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?visit_id=637697643572074146-3051197356&rd=1#intro) :

> You can offer new subscribers a discounted price for a specific
> duration. If you do, this must be within the accepted price range and
> cost less per day than the original price.

Of cores you can stop Introductory prices any time manually.

Comment: I don't think this satisfies my above problem.

Comment: OP is asking for a way to set up a permanent in app offer for say 50% off the subscription price